# IntelliJ doesn't find classes in the nearest package

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I do simple Java project (educational). Can't understand why class Client in package "client" doesn't see other classes from root "src".
How can I import class Connection to class Client?
Sorry if it's too stupid question, I've tried:

```
import Connection;
import *Connection;
import .Connection;
import /Connection;
```

[image: the problem]

Comment: A fully qualified classname is required for an import, like `import package.anotherPackage.Connection;`

Comment: As the tooltip suggest, use Alt+Shift+Enter to get import suggestions...

Comment: Ah, your `Connection` class is in the unnamed (a.k.a. default) package. You cannot use classes from the default package in named packages like `client`. Restructure the layout of your project so you don't have classes in the unnamed package, and all your classes are in a named package (or all classes are in the unnamed package, but really the unnamed package shouldn't be used for anything other than experiments or toy projects).